# Editor Color Scheme

Tags: powershell, editor, customization, syntax-highlighting

I'm using the standard editor in VSCode Powershell and
am looking for some documentation of the color scheme used.

- Remarks     are Green,
- MyVariable is Light Blue,
- PSVariable is Light Green,
  etc.

I want to know what color is used for what code elements in the standard Powershell Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Same concept of profiles for Powershell, same procedure.
The file created is called Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1 in the currentuser pattern.

[about_Profiles Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2)

To check:

```
Test-Path $PROFILE
```

To create in default scope:

```
New-Item -Path $PROFILE -Type File -Force
```

To edit:

```
code $PROFILE
```

Comment: I will get round to $Profile later.